# IF statement and few conditions in JAVA

Tags: java, if-statement

I need to check 9 conditions for true or false and they need to be all true in one time. 
How can it be possible checked, besides

```
if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3 ... && condition9) {
    ...
}
```

Think I used word "condition" right.

Comment: It mainly depends on the data structure in which you have your conditions.

Comment: Post the actual conditions. It's hard to come up with better way with just `condition`.

Comment: what wrong in your solution?

Comment: Why do you want something besides the right way to do it?

Comment: If the conditions are in an array you can always build a loop to "sum" them and use only that result in the if statement.

Comment: You could always use `if (!(condition1 || condition2 || condition3 ... || condition9))`

Comment: emm depending what the "condition" really is  ?

Comment: well if you need these 9 conditions to be true all at once (hence the &'s) and they are actually nine distinct conditions....not sure what else you can do

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to know if you don't show more code than that.....

However, if I only have that piece of code, I can recommend three things:

**1.** If you have this information, start with the condition that is most likely to be false, that may improve performance..... more information here [short circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

**2.** Another thing, if you have all the conditions in an array, you can loop trough the array... Something like this:

```
public boolean testCondition(boolean conditionsArray[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(!conditionsArray[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Post more code and I will try to improve my answer.

**3.** You might want to rethink about the data structures also. Probably something is not very clean in your design if you need to test for 9 given conditions like that (just probably).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I get into such a situation in code, I know I'm doing it wrong, and need to rethink my object structure.

However, just at the pure level of the question, as long as the conditions are in a collection of some kind, this will work:

```
    boolean allTrue = true;
    for (boolean condition : conditions) {
        allTrue &= condition;
    }
```

And then do the if on the allTrue variable. Note that I am assuming that the collection is not empty, or if it is, that should be regarded as a true condition.

Most likely in the real world you have to wrap these conditions in some kind of object with a common interface with a method that returns the boolean and use that, rather than having a collection of pure booleans.